# Notepad++ . how to replace "u" with you , "i" with I etc

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have to replace "u" with you , "i" with I etc in a document. Simple find and replace in notepad++ results in changing "u" even inside words like "much" with "myouch".
Kindly help.

Comment: doesn't notepad++ have a "Match Whole word" option?

Answer (score 6):

Use a regular expression search and replace:

```
\bu\b
```

Comment: Using `\b` is better than capturing with `(\s)` because the `\s` version will not find single letters adjacent to punctuation marks.

Answer (score 2):

In search: `(\s*)u(\s*)`

In replace: `\1you\2`

and check regular expression in the bottom.

edited for first and last positions. For uppercase, if you want to replace by "You", the simplest way is to make two replacements.

Comment: \1 \2 what does that mean?

Comment: The parenthesis arround the `\s` in the search pattern are here to capture what is inside (here every blank character: space, new line, tab,...). Then you can put what was inside in the replace string. Here, it's for not modify the text arround the replaced string. For example, you could have a new line just after a "u", you have to replace it by a new line after.

Comment: The answer was changed from `(\s)u(\s)` to `(\s*)u(\s*)` in an edit. The new version does not work because `\s*` will match zero white-space characters and so the whole RE can match the `u` withing `faulty`.

Comment: I've made this change to match u if it's at the first position. But using \b is better.

Answer (score 1):

select match case option also...see this...it works fine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To only change single-letter words, you must include a "Space" before and after both the single character you are searching for and the word you want to change that letter to.

Example:

In the Find What field, type Space u Space or the 3 characters between the quotation marks:

" u "

In the Replace With field, type Space you Space or the 5 characters between the quotation marks:

" you "

Comment: This fails at the ends of sentences, beginning and ends of lines, quotations, etc.